# Install WeasyPrint on Anaconda 4.2.0 using Python 3.5 on Windows

Tags: python, pdf-generation, anaconda

How does one easily install this (http://weasyprint.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install.html)
library using Anaconda 4.2.0 (Python 3.5). There are instructions on the weasyprint website, but I don't think it applies for Anaconda versions of Python. 
How would the instructions (on the website) change if I wanted to install weasyprint on Anaconda using Windows?

Answer (score 0):

I have installed WeasyPrint on Anaconda. The instructions are exactly the same except the first step. If you are using Anaconda, you already have Python installed and it is on your path.

If after following the instructions, you still get an error, you may have to edit your `PATH` variable to move the GTK folder `C:\Program Files\GTK3-Runtime Win64\bin` higher up on the list. I had a conflict with a dependency when it was at the bottom, which is where it goes by default.